# What is the difference if I start bash with "/bin/bash" or "/usr/bin/env bash"?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In shell scripts one specifies language interpreter on shebang(`#!`) line. As far as I know, it is recommended to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` because `env` is always located in `/usr/bin` directory while location of `bash` may vary from system to system. However, are there any technical differences if `bash` is started directly with `/bin/bash` or through `env` utility? In addition, am I correct that if I do not specify any variables for `env`, the `bash` is started in unmodified environment?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In one sense, using `env` could be considered "portable" in that the path to `bash` is not relevant (`/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/bash`, `/usr/local/bin/bash`, `~/bin/bash`, or whatever path) because it is specified in the environment. In this way, a script author could make his script easier to run on many different systems.

In another sense, using `env` to find `bash` or any other shell or command  interpreter is considered a security risk because an unknown binary (malware) might be used to execute the script. In these environments, and sometimes by managerial policy, the path is specified explicitly with a full path: `#!/bin/bash`.

In general, use `env` unless you know you are writing in one of these environments that scrutinize the minute details of risk.

When Ubuntu first started using `dash`, some time in 2011, many scripts were broken by that action. There was discussion about it on askubuntu.com. Most scripts were written `#!/bin/sh` which was a link to `/bin/bash`. The consensus was this: the script writer is responsible for specifying the interpreter. Therefore, if your script should always be invoked with BASH, specify it from the environment. This saves you having to guess the path, which is different on various Unix/Linux systems. In addition, it will work if tomorrow `/bin/sh` becomes a link to some other shell like `/bin/newsh`.

Another difference is that the `env` method won't allow the passing of arguments to the interpreter.

Comment: Regarding `env` as a security risk to find `bash`. Do you mean that if I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang, then bash is searched from my $PATH and for example if my $PATH is "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" and I have a malware named `bash` in `/usr/local/sbin` directory(`/usr/local/sbin/bash` is executed instead of `/usr/bin/bash` because `/usr/local/sbin` is before `/usr/bin` in $PATH), then this is a security risk?

Comment: Yes, but of more concern, the user's PATH could place the malware first in the PATH. Not every system is so rigorously scrutinized, but, for example, consider a system that has mission-critical services running in an environment where threats could be launched from anywhere. In some environments, like any organization under the DoD, an Information Assurance Officer may flag it while scrutinizing a system that is being tested for its Authority to Operate. Not all vulnerabilities are known, and specifying a full path mitigates the FUD.

Comment: `env -S` does pass arguments to the interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from that using `/usr/bin/env` is somewhat slower there is no difference, if you start a program which such a shebang. (Unless  `/bin/bash` doesn't exists but `bash` is somewhere (else) in the PATH)

`env` has the possibility to modify the environment of the invoked command, but that can only be used when `env` is started from the commandline, with in shebang line (depending on the OS) the options cannot be specified.

The [source of `env`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/env.c;h=270d08e3b121a7fcf8551bcbd071a3d208050ada;hb=HEAD) is rather small so you can verify what it is doing if you are familiar with C. Since `execvp` is used to call the program to be executed. There will not even be an `env` parent process if you inspect the process tree.

Comment: So in a nutshell `/usr/bin/env bash`, is exactly the same as to search for `bash` from $PATH?