# See if a script is running when using #!/usr/bin/env

Tags: shell-script, ps, shebang

I have tried migrating the shebang for my bash scripts from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and some of them were broken because they relied on this code that checks for existing instances of themselves runnning, and which works only with `#!/bin/bash`:

```
$ pidof -x myscript -o %PPID
```

What I would like to know is how can I reliably check if a script called by `env` is running, since most solutions I have tried will involve some dirty regex, and stilll end up being unreliable:

```
$ pgrep -f '(^|/)myscript(\s|$)'
```

Considering the path to my script is `/home/user/myscript`, the above code may return the PID for the following undesired commands:

```
editor /home/user/myscript
bash /tmp/myscript
bash /home/user/myscript with spaces
```

Comment: For why one would change the interpreter line in the first place, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/88257/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206350/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you could use `pgrep` to get PIDs of likely suspects, and inspect the first argument of those PIDs (available in `/proc/$PID/cmdline`). `/proc/$PID/cmdline` has all the arguments (including argument 0) of the process, separated ASCII NUL (`\0`).

Something like:

```
pgrep bash | xargs -I {} sed -nz '2{p; q}' /proc/{}/cmdline | grep -Fqzx "$0"
```

This assumes your `sed` and `grep` support null-separated lines. The `sed` prints the second line of the respective `cmdline` files (argument 1), which would be the script name. `grep` then looks for exact matches of your script name. You could do the entire match in `sed`, but I don't feel like juggling quotes.

This will fail if you call your script by different paths:

```
/home/user/myscript
cd /home; usr/myscript
myscript
```

However, it should be safe against whitespace in script names.

Comment: Hello, Happy New Year! What version of sed is this that supports null-separated new-lines? Mine doesn't: GNU sed 4.2.1.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior You too! mine is 4.2.2.

Comment: I have upgraded my sed, but when running your command, I get `xargs: sed: terminated by signal 13`.

Comment: According to `man 7 signal`, that's SIGPIPE - broken pipe. Some command in that pipeline terminated. I guess `grep` - probably your grep doesn't support `-z` either.

Comment: `-z` it supports, but for some reason it fails when I use `-z` together with `-q`, but that can be solved with `>/dev/null`. Now I'll give your command some tries, thanks!